# Google Analytics in my dashboard, users able to see their own analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Hey I was wondering if someone would know a solution to my problem connected with google analytics.

I would like to embed google analytics into my dashboard and allow anyone to "connect" to those analytics with his own api key or some different authentication, which would then serve as a connection to his page where google analytics script is and show those in my dashboard.

So basically I just need a simple way to fetch data from different pages with simple authentication. I can then handle that data with different graphs, piecharts or just use native google ones. I was already thinking about iframe with google analytics inside my dashboard but that solution seems kinda hacky and I wouldn't be able to show different data in the way I want. I would like a simple interface for user to just put a key or his username/pass to log in and see analytics from his page. Hopefully I made myself clear.

Currently I found only this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started, which requires user to create Client ID through some google developers - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#get-access-keys-for-your-application.

Sounds really complicated and I want just "copy" of google analytics page for my own project where users can put credentials and then see data alongside other things from my project. Project is basically some kind of CRM platform.

If anyone knows solution, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the Embed API ? Purely clientside code, users authenticate via their Google Account (so they are automatically connected to their own GA accounts) and you can use either Google Charts or your own visualizations. And at a basic level it's pretty much copy & paste. Apart from that, stackoverflow is generally not a "how to" page but a place where specific issues with code are discussed, so you should try something and if it does not work come back with a specific error message.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to achieve the following:

1. Get GA data per user
2. Apply custom presentation to the data
3. Control access and authentication yourself

To achieve all this you will need to build your own solution (e.g. a web page) which gets the data from GA using the API. Start here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that link explains a lot. But I have couple of questions as I don't understand all those terms in GA. If I want to run those GA requests like analytics.data.ga.get(), do I have to include some libraries in my website? And what can be the easiest solution to authenticate user, I see I can also use oauth2-token to make API calls. Perfect solution would be one input box where user puts his authentication (either apikey or token or smth) and clicks save settings and then I'm able to fetch that data for him on my website...

Comment: These are good questions but they are too general. You'll need to do some research and decide on the best solution for you.